# AngularJS service returning variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular 1.4 application where I have a service that encapsulates the communication with my backend. If I do something like following to return data from an endpoint. The Api service that I'm injecting encapsulates my $http ajax requests

```
function MyDataService(Api, $injector, $q, $log) {
    var self = this;
    function getAll(){
        return self.Api.get('/myData').then(function(data){
            self.data = data;
            return self.data;
        })
    }
    return self;
}
```

If I use this service method in a controller or other modules, Am I referencing directly that property? I mean, if I do a double binding in a controller and that variable change, self.data inside my service will change too? I think JS is using references by default.

Thank you very much

Comment: Is `self` your service or your controller?

Comment: My service. I will complete the code :)

Comment: Include $http for ajax call

Comment: @ManikandanVelayutham that is wrapped in my other Api service

Comment: oh ok. Then update that code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. you are referring the controller variable. use `angular copy` to avoid this. try this

```js
function getAll(){
    return self.Api.get('/myData').then(function(data){
        self.data = data;
        var retdata={};
        angular.copy(data, retdata)
        return retdata;
    })
 }
```

Comment: Or I can return data directly instead self.data. Am I wrong?